# Сериализация, собственные форматы, передача и сохранение данных. Уточните мои представления о механизмах

Tags: java

Как я понимаю, любой записанный файл, кроме бинарного,  это сериализованный массив данных.  В процессе сериализации в файл помимо самих данных, записывается и информация о программе в которая производит запись (поля классов, суперклассы их поля и т.д.).

Для каждого формата файла существует свой сериализатор, в котором определена структура хранения данных или сериализатор существует в единственном виде,  который при записи данных добавляет  к ним данные о полях именно той Вашей программы?

Скорее первый вариант,  потому что на каждом компьютере, есть программа с десериализатором именно этого формата.Например сам текст который я дописал в txt занимает куда меньше информации, чем созданый файл.  Этот файл уже хранит информацию о форматировании текста,  заголовок файла,  мета-данные.

На википедии написано,  что сериализация используется для передачи по сети файлов.  Но если это уже файл ,допустим формата txt, то зачем его еще раз сериализовывать.  Просто превращаем его снова в массив байтов, в которых уже закодировано расширение и мета данные.  А на том конце для воспроизведения файла используется десериализатор, но для его сохранения уже нечего не надо.  Будет сохранен этот массив байтов. А как его прочесть уже дело программы с десериализатором именно этого формата.

Comment: бинарный может так же содержать сериализованные данные. более того `ObjectOutputStream` пишет данные именно в бинарный файл.

Comment: а вопрос какой?

Comment: В середине текста есть строчка с вопросительным знаком)  я немного разобрался, но вот еще: сериализатор как то связан с форматом файла? Существуют разные алгоритмы сериализации? В чем различие?